# Is there any way to exclude the "meta", "rows", "statistics" fields from the ClickHouse FORMAT JSON query?

Tags: clickhouse

Query:

```sql
SELECT value FROM test.json_test FORMAT JSON
```

Response:

```json
{
    "meta":
    [
        {
            "name": "value",
            "type": "Int32"
        }
    ],

    "data":
    [
        {
            "value": 1
        }
    ],

    "rows": 1,

    "statistics":
    {
        "elapsed": 0.112135109,
        "rows_read": 1,
        "bytes_read": 4
    }
}
```

How to exclude unnecessary fields and leave only `data` field?

Comment: AFAIK there's currently no way to do so. What is the reason you need that for? Decrease response size?

Comment: I want to forward the json right away to the UI without pre processing the json in the middleware. I don't need additional fields because I already know the data types for the returned json and I don't want to exposure the underlying DB used to the end users.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude "statistics" from output:

> set output_format_write_statistics=0;

```sql
ubuntu-16gb-nbg1-1 :) select 1 format JSON;

SELECT 1
FORMAT JSON

{
    "meta":
    [
        {
            "name": "1",
            "type": "UInt8"
        }
    ],

    "data":
    [
        {
            "1": 1
        }
    ],

    "rows": 1
}

1 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.003 sec.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [JSONEachRow](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/interfaces/formats/#jsoneachrow) cannot be used straightforward because the result JSON is not valid.

You can play with grouping data to the array to get valid JSON:

```sql
SELECT
    groupArray(value) AS values,
    groupArray((value, name)) AS objects
FROM
(
    SELECT
        1 AS value,
        'str1' AS name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        2 AS value,
        'str2' AS name
)
FORMAT JSONEachRow

/* Result:
{"values":[1,2],"objects":[[1,"str1"],[2,"str2"]]}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

where you try running your query?
maybe you can try filter this output via pipelines and JQ

```
clickhouse-client -q "SELECT value FROM test.json_test FORMAT JSON" | jq .data
```

Comment: I run it with clickhouse jdbc driver - https://github.com/blynkkk/clickhouse4j.